# (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name

Tags: ssl, curl, nginx, lets-encrypt, proxypass

I am trying to generate the LetsEncrypt certificate files, and I am using the following commands:

```
./certbot-auto --config /etc/letsencrypt/configs/milhas.brau.io.conf certonly
```

The files are generated correctly, but in "curl" command results the message:

```
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'milhasplus.brau.io'
```

**milhas.brau.io.conf**

```
# the domain we want to get the cert for;
# technically it's possible to have multiple of this lines, but it only worked
# with one domain for me, another one only got one cert, so I would recommend
# separate config files per domain.
domains = milhas.brau.io

# increase key size
rsa-key-size = 2048 # Or 4096

# the current closed beta (as of 2015-Nov-07) is using this server
server = https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

# this address will receive renewal reminders
email = braulio@braulioti.com.br

# turn off the ncurses UI, we want this to be run as a cronjob
text = True

# authenticate by placing a file in the webroot (under .well-known/acme-challenge/)
# and then letting LE fetch it
authenticator = webroot
webroot-path = /var/www/letsencrypt/
```

**NGINX config file**

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl default_server;
    server_name  milhas.brau.io;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/milhas.brau.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/milhas.brau.io/privkey.pem;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://80.241.208.103:8084/;
    }
}
```

**curl result**

```
$ curl -v https://milhasplus.brau.io/autenticacao/docs/termo_uso

*   Trying 80.241.208.103...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to milhasplus.brau.io (80.241.208.103) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: PROFILE=SYSTEM
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=milhas.brau.io
*  start date: Aug 25 10:28:56 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 23 10:28:56 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match milhasplus.brau.io
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'milhasplus.brau.io'
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'milhasplus.brau.io'
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks valid to me, is green in Firefox https://milhas.brau.io

Comment: Thanks @DanieleDellafiore. My problem was actually another one. Sorry my mistakes

Comment: @BráulioFigueiredo what was it? I am having the same with multiple hostnames...

Comment: @FrancescoGualazzi this steps works for me:

1 - I made the update of Python version 2.7.5 (in my case the server is CentOS 7)
2 - I set all my files in Nginx only as http.
3 - I used the letsencrypt-auto command for the system to update the Nginx files